# GRASS Toolbar for QGIS missing the tools I expect to see

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, configuration

I am trying to learn GRASS and QGIS using the instructions here: https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/grass_integration/grass_integration.html. I am running on Windows and open the version of QGIS with GRASS. When I enable the GRASS plugin, however, I see only two buttons on the toolbar. The panel is telling me to open a GRASS mapset but the button to create a new mapset is not visible in the toolbar. What am I missing here?

I'm using QGIS 2.14.3 with GRASS 7.0.4

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The QGIS 2.6 documentation does not cover the new GRASS 7 plugin.

You can create a new mapset from the menu

[image]

or open an existing one from the browser

[image]